# haproxy remove trailing slash

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I would like to redirect request from:

```
http://myrepo/mytest.git/
```

to

```
http://myrepo/mytest.git
```

so, removing the trailing slash in haproxy. any hint ?

Here's what I tried both in frontend and backend:

```
 reqrep ^(.*)[\/]$ \1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
frontend nginx
    bind *:5000
    mode http
    option  forwardfor  
    option   httpclose
    acl old_url path_beg -i /mytest.git
    reqrep ^(.*)[\ /]$     \1
    redirect prefix / code 301 if old_url
    default_backend tomcats

backend tomcats
    mode http
    server tomcat01 X.X.X.X:8080 check inter 2000
```

Comment: Won't this result in an infinite redirect?