# HAProxy remove trailing slashes

Tags: regex, load-balancing, haproxy

I need to redirect all urls to urls with non trailing slashes

Example:

> http://www.example.com/education/ -> http://www.example.com/education
>
> http://www.example.com/blah// -> http://www.example.com/blah
>
> http://www.example.com/blah/blah/// -> http://www.example.com/blah/blah

This is what I have for now:

```
frontend localnodes
    bind 127.0.0.1:80

    acl has_trailing_slash path_end  /
    reqrep ^(.*)[\ /]$ \1
    redirect prefix / code 301 if has_trailing_slash
```

Refer: [haproxy remove trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640934/haproxy-remove-trailing-slash)

But this is just making the browser enter a redirect loop of 301s. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex works for only one `/` at the end as `.*` eats all character till last `/`.

Try this regex:

```
^(.*?)[\/]+$ \1
```

`.*?` makes it non greedy here.

`[/]+` for one or more slashes.

Comment: This is not working in HAProxy 1.8+. Does anyone know how to resolve it in newer version?